# Glassfish Httpd error bad gateway

Tags: tomcat, glassfish, apache, mod-jk

I have deployed Apache Roller 5 on glassfishv3 which httpd as front end.
Roller have running works fine, but it's often like **bad gateway** when i accessed it.

i this case, configuration on woker properties like this

workers.properties

```
worker.list=roller2
worker.roller2.port=8009
worker.roller2.host=localhost
worker.roller2.type=ajp13
worker.roller2.lbfactor=1
worker.roller2.socket_keepalive=1
worker.roller2.socket_timeout=60
```

and on virtual host

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName doma.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/roller
            JkMount /roller/* roller2
            JkMount /roller roller2 
   </VirtualHost>
```

i check on the mod_jk log on httpd error message like this

```
ajp_connection_tcp_get_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1150): (roller2) can't receive the response header message  from tomcat, network problems or tomcat (127.0.0.1:8009) is down (errno=11)
```

are there other configuration for tunning the glassfish ? or any suggestion to solve this cause ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to setup network listener to handle the mod_jk requests properly. I've gotten the same error for example by using a wrong port in my listener settings. To see how to setup a listener in Glassfish see also [this link](http://wikis.sun.com/display/GfLB/2010/12/31/Configure+Apache+with+mod_jk+on+GlassfishV3).